# How to return the equivalent of "Text" in Excel VBA from a cell that has the word Text written in it?

Tags: string, excel, text, cell, vba

I'm trying to use VBA to send a PDF copy of a worksheet. Everything works when my code looks like this:

```
With OutlookMail
.To = "email_address@email.com"
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "No Subject"
.Body = ""
.Attachments.Add FileName
.Send
End With
```

But I want to replace the email address in `.To` to an email address that has been written into the active worksheet within a cell that is formatted as text. What I've tried is this:

```
With OutlookMail
    .To = Range("K4").Text
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "No Subject"
    .Body = ""
    .Attachments.Add FileName
    .Send
    End With
```

Which I think should work but for some reason it doesn't. The cell is merged from K4 to N4 but when in a worksheet if I try `=K4` it returns what is in the entire cell so I think this should be okay. I'm sure this is a very easy question but I've tried looking things up and tried using `CStr(Range("K4").Text)` instead but no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Would you mind taking off the `.Text` and then trying?

Comment: Tried with `.To = Range("K4")` but no luck. The email is in the form `lastname.firstname@gmail.com`. I also tried `Range("K4").Value` and no luck either in case that helps.

Comment: I don't see why it would make a difference, but you could also try `Cells(4,11)`. I wrote code much like this not long ago and what you are doing seems to be fine to me.

Comment: Hmmm... Still no dice. Tried `Cells(4,11)` as you mentioned then switched back to `"lastname.firstname@gmail.com"`. The second came in but no sign of the first one.

Comment: Does anything show up in the `To` part of the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Sheets("SheetName").Range("K4").Value`

Comment: Ahhhhh thank you. I forgot that I changed the active sheet. However, I had to modify this slightly to `Sheets("Sheetname").Range("K4").Value` which may be because I am using Excel VBA 2007.